# find left and right turn in android mobile

Tags: android

how to find out mobile turn left and right.depending on left and right turn i need to one ball?

Comment: What are you talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [SensorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html) to detect phone shaking.

```
// Need to implement SensorListener
public class ShakeActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener {
    // For shake motion detection.
    private SensorManager sensorMgr;
    private long lastUpdate = -1;
    private float x, y, z;
    private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
    private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 800;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...... // other initializations
    // start motion detection
    sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    boolean accelSupported = sensorMgr.registerListener(this,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    if (!accelSupported) {
        // on accelerometer on this device
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
    }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
    if (sensorMgr != null) {
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorMgr = null;
        }
    super.onPause();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // only allow one update every 100ms.
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) &gt; 100) {
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
        lastUpdate = curTime;

        x = values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
        y = values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
        z = values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

        float speed = Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z)
                              / diffTime * 10000;
        if (speed &gt; SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
            // yes, this is a shake action! Do something about it!
        }
        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
        last_z = z;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the tutorial, [detect shake motion](http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/17/how-to-detect-shake-motion-in-android-part-i/)

Comment: exactly i am looking this.i am developing game.when i use this code my total programming is not working.it is going to struck