# Android - Pulling Motion with Phone

Tags: android

Does anybody know if there is a way to detect when a user makes a motion with the phone. In particular I am trying to detect when the user makes a quick movement backward (or towards themselves).

Anybody know of any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the Accelerometer. Here's an example class that implements a the SensorEventListener, which listens in for sensor motion.

```
public class AccelerometerHandler implements SensorEventListener
{
    float accelX;
    float accelY;
    float accelZ;

    public AccelerometerHandler(Context paramContext)
    {
        SensorManager localSensorManager = (SensorManager)paramContext.getSystemService("sensor");

        if (localSensorManager.getSensorList(1).size() != 0)
            localSensorManager.registerListener(this, (Sensor)localSensorManager.getSensorList(1).get(0), 1);
    }

    public float getAccelX()
    {
        return this.accelX;
    }

    public float getAccelY()
    {
        return this.accelY;
    }

    public float getAccelZ()
    {
        return this.accelZ;
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor paramSensor, int paramInt)
    {
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent paramSensorEvent)
    {
        this.accelX = paramSensorEvent.values[0];
        this.accelY = paramSensorEvent.values[1];
        this.accelZ = paramSensorEvent.values[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: The set of the X, Y, Z values is not an atomic operation and therefore this 'handler' is not thread-safe. Please implement the [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncrgb.html](Java - Synchronized Class) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the sensorListener as:

```
public class MotionActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener {

}
```

It has a method on onSensorChanged,All the functionality on shake can be implemented in this method:

```
public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {


}
```

You can visit the link [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) to work with sensors in android

Also visit the stackoverflow [internal link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801345/find-left-and-right-turn-in-android-mobile) for more information.